# Creation of excel file using python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pywin32

Is there any way  to create excel objects using pywin32 even if MS-OFFICE suite is not installed on windows based system ?

Comment: "using pywin32" is that a strict requirement?

Comment: Yeah , because i have already developed scripts around that for better control of features in excel.

Comment: I doubt it... What you can do is create `.xlsx` files with `openpyxl`. but it will be limited to data (no macros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("C:\\Users\\your_path_here\\Desktop\\sample.xlsx")
```

See this link for details.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl